# How's it possible to assign variable where expression needed in java?

Tags: java, python

I've searched about the difference between expression and statement, and a question came up.

In C or java, I can assign variable in if statement like this.

```java
int a;
// someFunc returns an integer value
if ((a=someFunc()) == 1) {
    // do something
}
```

In contrary, python doesn't allow this.

```py
if (a = someFunc() is 1):
    # do something
```

of course, following PEP 572, after python 3.8 i can use it,
but should use `:=` symbol.

however, `a=someFunc()` is not expression but statement which returns nothing after execution. right?
so, python's way of interpreting code looks reasonable, and java's doesn't

but, how's it possible to interpret that way of code in java or C? and why is it allowed?

Comment: Does `1` mean `true`?

Comment: well, i can't figure out what you mean. that java code would be interpreted as `if ( a == 1)` and if a is 1 then true, if not, false.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I will try explaining this by taking your example:

```
int a;
if((a = someFunc()) == 0) {
    //do something here
}
```

Over here the below sequence is followed:

1. someFunc() method is called, which after getting executed is expected to return some integer value as per our variable declared.
2. After the value is returned from the method it gets stored inside the variable a.
3. Now the whole statement is present inside parentheses is treated as the value present inside variable a, i.e. **(a = someFunc())** becomes **a** which again is an integer value return by calling the method **someFunc()**.
4. Now this value is getting compared with 0 and the if statement is validated accordingly.

Comment: thanks, but still cant understand. you said `(a=someFunc()) becomes a`. but, I'm wondering that " `a=someFunc()` is statement which is not expression, so it would be **consumed and returns nothing**, but how can it remains". it's a trivial question but confusing me.

Comment: lets understand it like this, in java when you write `int a = someFunc();` then what happens is someFunc() returns value and stored in a. Now when the statement is terminated the final value it gives is the value present inside a. And this is not just limited to if statement you can try this inside a print statement as well.

Comment: For example: 
`int a;
System.out.println(a = 5);`
This will print 5 in the console. So what happens is when the statement is terminated the last value which is stored in the memory referred by a variable is retained over there. In the same way when we write `if((a == someFunc()) == 0)` so in the end of the first parentheses the value referred by variable **a** in the memory is retained and then it is used to compare it with 0.